# mysql removed character encoding of text

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, character-encoding

I have to following code that runs fine when i run it on the browser and echo out the text, it displays proper arabic characters but the problem is when i save it into the mysql database, everything starts to garble up like in the screenshot below. 
    [image]

Here is the character encoding set on the database [image]

and finally my code. I am totally confused and frustrated now on how to fix all this and I haven't found any solutions to this so far.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset= Windows-1256');

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client(); 

$lebanonfiles = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.lebanonfiles.com');

$news_container = $lebanonfiles->filter('#mcs4_container .line');


$news_container->each(function($node) { 

    $temp = explode(' ',trim($node->text()));


    $db = new MysqliDb (Array (
                            'host' => 'localhost',
                            'username' => 'root', 
                            'password' => 'rolemodel',
                            'db'=> 'wade3',
                            'charset' => 'utf8_general_ci'));


    $temp_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($temp[0]));

    $temp_text = utf8_decode(str_replace($temp[0]," ",$node->text()));

    $temp_url = "http://www.lebanonfiles.com";

    $data = Array(
            'updated' => $temp_time,
            'scraped_on' => $temp_time,
            'link' =>$temp_url,
            'title'=> $temp_text,
            'feedsource' => 'lebanonfiles'
        );      

    $db->insert('news', $data );

});
```

Comment: `utf8_general_ci` is not a charset, it's a collation. `utf8` is the charset.

Comment: @deceze I changed it but that didnt solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change charset to

```
'charset' => 'cp1256'
```

because client encoding must match the actual encoding of the data, which is windows-1256 as http header suggests.

remove the line

```
$temp_text = utf8_decode(str_replace($temp[0]," ",$node->text()));
```

because there is no utf to decode in your data.

Comment: I don't know why it is so but keeping the utf8_decode part helps me get the proper text into the database. Went through a lot of combinations before stumbingling into it.

Answer (score -1):

1. as its been said, set charset to utf8.
2. make sure table charset is set to utf8 as well.
3. source charset on www.lebanonfiles.com is windows-1256.
4. replace utf8_decode with $temp_text = iconv("cp1256", "utf-8", str_replace($temp[0]," ",$node->text()));

that should work.

if you do not have iconv () enabled, try http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Answer (score -2):

Try to set the charset to UTF-8: `mysqli_set_charset($yourConnection, "utf8");`

Comment: This is not the answer, add it as a comment.